# Carregar imagem e pegar o suas dimensões

Tags: javascript

Ao executar:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "./image.png";
var w = image.width;
```

a variável 'w' é igual a '0', existe uma maneira de capturar as dimensões da 'image'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira que encontrei foi:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = './image.png';
image.onload = function () {
   var w = image.width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Muito possivelmente a sua imagem não está a ser carregada correctamente. Experimente o seguinte:

```js
var img = new Image();

img.onerror = function() {
  console.warn("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar a imagem");
}

// esta imagem não existe.
// troque pelo caminho para a sua imagem
img.src = "http://www.apimages.com/Images/Ap_Creative_Stock_Header_blah.jpg";

console.log(img.width);
```

O *handler* `onerror` pode ser chamado por [várias razões](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Errors). Entre elas:

- A propriedade `src` está vazia ou nula
- A propriedade `src` tem uma URL igual à página onde o utilizador se encontra
- A imagem que tentou carregar está corrompida
- A imagem não existe
- Os metadados da imagem estão corrompidos (impossibilitando a análise das dimensões da imagem)
- A imagem está num formato não suportado pelo seu navegador

Após a imagem ser carregada com sucesso, a propriedade `width` e `height` terão as dimensões da imagem carregada.

```js
var img = new Image();

img.onerror = function() {
  console.log("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar a imagem");
}

// esta imagem existe
img.src = "http://www.apimages.com/Images/Ap_Creative_Stock_Header.jpg";
console.log(img.width);
document.body.appendChild(img);
```